# Add secondary attributes tab to woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I need to add another tab to product tabs section of woocommerce with the name of features and it's content fills just like attributes section. the source be same but data store in separate meta data and show it in another tab in product page view section.
any Idea how should to do this?
thank you in advance

Comment: Search in stackoverflow: "add a product tab in woocommerce" and look to the woocommerce template `single-product/tabs/additional-information.php` source code

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my code**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );

function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
$tabs['featurestab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Features', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 15,
    'callback'  => 'features_tab_content');
  return $tabs;
}

function features_tab_content() {
  echo 'Your product ('.get_the_ID().') features.';
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but my main problem is that how to show exact content as attributes tabs in this new tab but store the data in different meta data.

Comment: ACF(https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and then how you want (https://i.imgur.com/S1oPhtq.png) can be content, repeater or how you want it